# Git pushes HEAD -> master despite set-upstream-to and push.default

Tags: git, smartgit

I have a git repo in use without issue for a couple of years. I use SmartGit for convenience to do most things.

I recently noticed that while doing a push from SmartGit from dev branch, the dialog it presents for confirmation says "Push current branch 'dev' to 'master'" instead of dev to dev as was previously the case.

I switch to git cmd line to compare behavior and find that it also wants to push to master:

```
$ git push --dry-run
To https://github.com/some_repo.git
   c00bb9e..6a8ade4  HEAD -> master
```

Pushing with a refspec works as expected, but I cant seem to find a way to tell SmartGit to use that refspec or how it decides that it will be pushing dev -> master.

```
$ git push origin dev --dry-run
To https://github.com/some_repo.git
   428dd9b..6a8ade4  dev -> dev
```

Git status and refs show as expected:

```
$git status
On branch dev
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/dev
```

My config push.default is set as 'simple' which should mean that current will push to same name on remote and complain if no match.

```
git config push.default
simple
```

I have also reset the 'upstream-to' and still a plain git push ends up wanting to do HEAD -> master.

```
$git branch --set-upstream-to origin/dev
Branch dev set up to track remote branch dev from origin by rebasing.
```

I'm out of ideas on what could be the cause of this and how to get back to a simple git push going to the branch matching current and/or how to get SmartGit to stop offering to push current -> master.

Git version: 2.5.0

SmartGit version: 8.0.3 #8135

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `git-push(1)`:

> When the command line does not specify what to push with `<refspec>...` arguments or `--all`, `--mirror`, `--tags` options, the command finds the default `<refspec>` by consulting `remote.*.push` configuration, and if it is not found,       honors `push.default` configuration to decide what to push (See `git-config`(1) for the meaning of `push.default`).

It sounds like you have `remote.dev.push` set to `HEAD`.

Comment: Excellent! 

Indeed my .git/config file for this repo has:
        [remote "origin"]
 url = https://github.com/somewhere/somerepo.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 push = HEAD:refs/heads/master

No clue how that push line got there. With it gone all is normal again.